# Ломается кирилица в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++

Изначально проблема состояла в том, что при отладке кода в консоли вместо русскоязычных символов выводились ???. Решил ее путем сохранения файла в кодировке 1251, но в таком случае, после закрытия файла в Visual Studio 2019, весь русскоязычный текст в файле меняется на êëàâèàòóðå ìîáèëüíîãî

Помогите грамотно решить эту проблему

Данный код присутсвтует в начале main()

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Comment: Данный код, естественно присутствует 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
 SetConsoleCP(1251);
 SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

Comment: свойства консоли -> попробуите поменять шрифт на Lucida Console

Comment: Менял. Сейчас проблема не в консоле, в самой консоле кирилица, а вот в Visual Studio вместо русских символов такая фигня êëàâèàòóðå ìîáèëüíîãî

Comment: А не проще консоль в utf8 перевести? chcp 65001 вроде

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru"); //в начале функции main()
```

Comment: Данный код, естественно присутствует setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); SetConsoleCP(1251); SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

Comment: SetConsoleCP(1251); SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); //это вам не надо